# How do I use map() to apply an operation to each element of a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, functional-programming, dictionary

I've got a piece of code that works fine. It basically loops through each element of a hash using `foreach()` and applies a transformation to it using a regular expression, like so :

```
foreach my $key ( keys( %{$results} ) ) {
   $results->{$key}{uri} =~ s/\".*\/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))\"/\/resources\/uploads\/$1/gi;
}
```

$results is a hashref returnd by DBI's `fetchall_hashref()` function.

Just out of curiosity, I wanted to see if I could rewrite it using `map()` instead, as shown below :

```
map {
   $results{$_}{uri} =~ s/\".*\/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))\"/\/resources\/uploads\/$1/gi
} keys %{$results};
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I've tried all sorts of things but so far without success. Anybody knows how to do this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

*The corrected code, as answered by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth):*

```
map {
   $results->{$_}{uri} =~ s/\".*\/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))\"/\/resources\/uploads\/$1/gi
} keys %{$results};
```

and the improved version with less *leaning toothpicks* suggested by [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-unur)

```
map {
   $results->{$_}{uri} =~ s{".*/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))"}{/resources/uploads/$1}gi
} keys %{$results};
```

Comment: One thing you might be interested in investigating is using different delimiters for your regexes. For example s@ @ @ would save you a few \'s. Also, nitpicking, the `\.*` is probably not what you meant, and the \ in \" is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the regex tips. We'll definitely look into it. :-)

Comment: @GeneQ `s{".*/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))"}{/resources/uploads/$1}gi;` Leaning toothpicks can play games with your vision.

Comment: @Sinan Indeed. Toothpicks do hurt my eyes. But its legacy code, so I'm cleaning it up bit by bit. Reducing toothpicks is surely next on the list of stuff to cleanup. Thanks guys for all the great regex suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the map version, you've mistakenly changed `$results->{` to `$results{`.  Put the -> back in and it should work.

Comment: Ah, you're right! All bugs are indeed shallow with enough Stackoverflow eyeballs. ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It's worth mentioning that you could get away with

```
$_->{uri} =~ s/foo/bar/ for values %$results;
```

in this case. Poking around in the data structure doesn't disturb the references that make it up.

Comment: Cool. Once again this proves that there's always more than one (surprising) way to do things in Perl. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The second piece of code uses a hash but the first one uses a hash reference. The following seems to work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $results = {
    a => {uri => "\"c/x.png\"" },
    b => {uri => "\"d/y.jpeg\""}
};

map {
   $results->{$_}{uri} =~ 
       s/\".*\/(.*\.*(gif|jpe?g|png))\"/\/resources\/uploads\/$1/gi
} keys %{$results};

for my $k (keys %$results) {
    print "$k $results->{$k}{uri}\n";
}
```